# Calling async .net framework methods from powershell. Possible deadlock issue

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I'm having problems calling an async method in a dll created in .NET framework 4.7 from a powershell script. The code works fine when called from other C# code, but locks up when called from powershell.

The first writeline before we await is printed, then the process waits forever.

C# library:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AwaitTest
{  
    public static class SimpleTestClient
    {
        public static async Task Start()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting ready to await");
            await Task.Delay(waitTime * 1000);
            Console.WriteLine("done");
        }
    }
}
```

Powershell:

```
Add-Type -Path "..\AwaitTest\bin\AwaitTest.dll"


function StartModules()
{
    [AwaitTest.SimpleTestClient]::Start().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
}
```

Comment: Which is the definition of `waitTime`? Anyway this function will end immediately because nothing is waiting for the `Task` to be terminated

Comment: Tested your code directly in PowerShell using `Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"...Your C# Code Above..."@` and creating an `int` called `waitTime` with a value of ***3*** and all works as expected. As @Marco asks, what's your definiton of waitTime?